# Which functions are needed for secure form inputs?

Tags: php, forms, security, input

On my registration form I have four inputs:

```
username  
password
email address
web address
```

Can't figure which off all available sanitizing  methods is really needed:

```
strip_tags()
substr()
mysql_real_escape_string()
trim()
htmlentities()
addslashes()
. . . (you may add more)
```

Somewhere I found that a function is a `must have`, somewhere this function is declared as `deprecated` or `less valuable the another one ...`

Could someone be so kind to create a list of priorities for all four inputs above.

Note: `PDO - prepared statements` are already used for communication with database.

Comment: There is no silver bullet. The way you sanitize the data depends **ONLY** on a way data is used. What do you need to sanitize the data for?

Comment: @zerkms, this is registration form. So I need to enter a new user into db, for login etc. later

Comment: I have nothing to add. Each thing requires its own sanitizing strategy. If you ask something more particular, without "etc" etc, then we could answer.

Comment: Are you using real prepared statements or emulated ones?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

First you need to be clear about hat for you like to sanitize.

Because you use allready [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) there is no need for:
[mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

If you like to deny you users the use of html, to avoid [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) you should perhaps use
[strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

To secure your html display agains not printable characters
[htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)
But in times of UTF-8 its a little obsolet.

For password input it can be used
[trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)
because it helps if youser copys passwords with leading / attached space.
Because outlook add spaces. But not everybody think this is an good idea, to trim passwords.

Depends on your Templating system it could be an good idea to use 
[addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)
for pre defined input values like

```
<input type="text" value="<?php addslashes($value); ?>" />
```

because it could be possible to do:

```
my value " /><script>evil things</script><
```

To have some kind of XSS in autocomplete forms.

Comment: GreenRover, thanks a lot. Very usefull for me. btw you have a typo `tape` - `type`

Comment: `addslashes` is entirely irrelevant to html.

Comment: "For password input it is an good idea to use trim() because it helps if youser copys passwords with leading / attached space." --- it is **STUPID** idea. The passwords especially should be left unchanged

Comment: @zerkms i am not your oppion, passwords should never have leading or attached spaces. This only gets you in trouble with users the copys password from outlook and then call the support. But this is an oppion!

Comment: "passwords should never have leading or attached spaces" --- you're so wrong. Passwords should contain whatever user passes and whatever user wants. Adding any artificial constraints (limitations) on the passwords - is the biggest incomprehension in security.

Comment: @GreenRover, maybe to create some annotations for users that only alphanum. are allowed (no spaces), and then make trim()

Comment: You don't use `strip_tags()` to prevent HTML input. You either use HTML purifier (if you want to allow some HTML) or `htmlspecialchars()` if you want to prevent any HTML. The use of `htmlentities()` is only good if you want to make your documents twice the size. Just use `htmlspecialchars()` and don't forget to pass the encoding as argument. `addslashes()`? You don't need that. `trim()` for passwords terrible idea as @zerkms already stated.

Comment: @PeeHaa, thanks. Do you know why is this block of comments dimmed on my screen ?

Answer (score 7):

In a few words:

1. When you add your data to database - use PDO's prepared statements with placeholders. That's it, nothing else is required.
2. When you output something from anywhere on the html page - you need to perform `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`, where the `$string` is the string you want to output in a "safe" manner.

Comment: zekerms, thanks. I use placedholders. Are you really sure about the first part of your answer ?

Comment: @Alegro: no, I intentionally wrote a wrong answer just because I like to write wrong answers. You're free to add 10 more functions from your question to feel more secured ;-)

Comment: zerkms, maybe you should relax. Thanks for help.