# Form Input Values and Quote Symbols

Tags: php, html

I have a form which users can edit.

One part of the form is a title field.

I get the previous title value and insert it into the field via PHP:

```
<input id="title" value=".$previousValue.">
```

The problem is, when the title has a " in it.

Say if the title was:

```
test"
```

It will only show this in the browser:

```
test
```

Upon an element inspection the " is there so nothing wrong with the PHP.

How can I get the quote to show up on the browser?

Comment: Check out threads/question like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314009/which-functions-are-needed-for-secure-form-inputs) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace the quotation mark with an html entity, as otherwise the browser will think you are simply trying to close the value attribute:

```
<input id="title" value="<?php echo str_replace('"', '&quot;', $previousValue); ?>">
```

**Edit:** Or, as others have correctly pointed out, you can use a shortcut which will catch other cases as well:

```
<input id="title" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($previousValue); ?>">
```

Comment: .... that is not how you echo out strings in html code from PHP....

Comment: Yes, sorry, copy-paste error. Fixed.

Comment: :-D @DerekHendersonnnnnn

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="title" value="test""> <<<--- see the issue there?
```

You have to escape your quotes:

```
<input id="title" value="test&quot;">
```

So in PHP:

```
<input id="title" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($previousValue)?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always use `htmlspecialchars($your_variable)` when you output to html. That will encode characters like `"`, `>`, etc. so that they will not break the html.